# Rails 4 app with precompiled assets on Elastic Beanstalk with Puma and Nginx serving page with old asset links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I have to precompile assets locally in order for one of my JS plugins to work correctly.

Whenever I make a change to any asset and precompile, I get a new version in public/assets, and the old one is there, too. When I run locally in production mode, I am served a page with the new assets.

When I deploy to EB, the pages always contain links to the old assets.

Of course, application.html.erb uses the dynamic css link tag: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>`

production.rb contains:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

I think this must have something to do with Nginx or some sort of caching in EC2 on the html files because puma runs locally.

I have tried:

- Different browser, PC, cleared cache, disable cache. It is not the browser.
- Setting send file off in nginx.conf.
- Setting cache expiration to -1 for html and confirmed with curl that I receive Cache-Control: no-cache
- Renamed entire app/current folder. I still receive a page, but it is missing the CSS. Where are the files that are actually used after a server is started?
- `rake tmp:clear` on the server.
- Looking all over the server for any nginx or puma cache. I found nothing.
- Researching for hours on end over the past 2 years.

The only thing that ever works is to `rake assets:clobber`, create a new EB environment, and deploy a few times. Sometimes, even that doesn't work.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

After additional countless hours of failing to solve this, I noticed a variable in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration settings that I had been changing from the default value. RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION - I was setting it to true since I was trying to manage the asset compilation myself. Flipping this back to false fixed my issue and significantly increased my deployment time. My third-party javascripts and gems all work correctly as well.

I still think this is a workaround because I should be able to precompile manually. However, it is good enough for me at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with caching assets on staging or production server. When I checked `Last-Modified` attribute of an asset file, for example with `curl -I http://url-to-the-asset-file` server returned old (cached) file.

What solve the issue was updating assets version in production.rb file. It will force assets to recompile with new MD5 hash fingerprint.

```
# config/environments/production.rb

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.1'
```

Hopefully this will help you or at least give some guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the version, the assets were all recompiled, and it did not help. It seems like it is something to do with the actual html that is being served. It is still trying to link to the old version.

Comment: Your html is still pointing (trying to serve) assets with old fingerprint and, as I understand it, changing assets version should force an application to generate html that points to assets with a new fingerprint. The only thing that comes to my mind is to try to restart the server but if it is already done during deployment than I don't know what could be a problem :(